# Characterization of $L^2$ operators that commute with multiplication by continuous functions

Tags: functional-analysis

Suppose $T$ is a bounded operator from $L^2$ to $L^2$ that commutes with pointwise multiplication by any continuous function $g$. That is, if $f\in L^2$,

$$gT(f)=T(gf).$$

Why must $T$ necessarily be multiplication by a $L^\infty$ function?

I am asking this question in order to understand the answer of Matthew Daws [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29704/why-are-translation-invariant-operators-on-l2-multiplier-operators)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that underlying measure space is $\sigma$-finite

If underlying measure space is finite just set $f=1$ and recall that all continuous functions (denoted by $g$) are dense in $L_2$.

To show that $T(1)$ is in $L_\infty$ you need to note that 
$$
\Vert g T(1)\Vert_2=\Vert T(g)\Vert_2\leq \Vert T\Vert\Vert g\Vert_2
$$ 
and use the following fact: If $\Vert gh\Vert_2\leq C\Vert g\Vert_2$ for all $g\in L_2$, then $h\in L_\infty$ and what is more $\Vert h\Vert_\infty\leq C$.

Otherwise decompose it onto disjoint union of finite measurable subsets and reduce your problem to the previous case.

Comment: So this shows that $T$ is multiplication by some $m$. How does one show this $m$ is in $L^\infty$?

Comment: @Potato see edits

Comment: Thank you! $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $

Comment: @Norbert: That "following fact" is the crux of the problem; not giving its proof is like not proving anything.

Comment: It is a well-known fact. I just reduced the original problem to it. You can add the proof for the "following fact" if you wish.